# Copy data on boot menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, backup, cmd.exe

My PC down and now I can just connect to it via command line window via bootable Windows 10 installation USB. U can list the drive that I want to copy and plug another USB for copying files. At this stage I cannot list the USB via `dir` command (but I can list the C drive). So:

**1.** How can I copy some folders in C drive to the USB? I do not want to plug out hard drive for this operation.

**2.** Is there another option to connect this PC at the boot state from another PC via USB, etc? What is the proper way to copy these folders?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `diskpart` to get the list of drives.
Drive Letters can be mapped differently when booting from a usb drive.

Run the following Command to get a diskpart shell.

```
diskpart
```

Then run this inside the diskpart shell.

```
list volume
```

And you will get something like this (It may be different for you.).

```
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     C   System       NTFS   Partition     99 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 3     F   Data (local  NTFS   Partition    365 GB  Healthy
```

Then Look for your drive in there (Ways to do so is to look for the label or drive size.).

On the Row where the drive is there is a column called "Ltr" in that column you will find the drive letter for your drive

For example the data partition's drive letter is "F:".

when your done type `exit` to return to the cmd shell and try to use the `dir` command again using the drive letter you found.

For your 2th question: No. Your firmware must support some kind of target disk mode feature. And even if it did I don't think it will support USB.